# error C2016: C requires that a struct or union has at least one member from struct

Tags: c, struct

When I do something like this with 2 header files: headerfile_1.h and headerfile_2.h
I get error: error C2016: C requires that a struct or union has at least one member from struct A definition in headerfile_1.h

In headerfile_1.h

```
#include "headerfile_2.h"
struct a;

struct a{
    B bb;
}A;
```

In headerfile_2.h

```
typedef struct b{
  void (*func0)(A *aa);
}B;
```

Please help me understand, where am I going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: How can you use `A` (and not even `struct A`) in headefile_2, without having the definition of `A` (which is in headerfile_1)?

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to do won't work because you have circular dependencies between the two header files:

headerfile_1:

```
struct A{
    B bb;  /* Use of B, therefore B needs to be defined before A */
};
```

headerfile_2:

```
typedef struct b{
    void (*func0)(A a); /* Use of A, therefore A needs to be defined before B */
} B;
```

Impossible.

One thing you can do, is to change definition of `func0` to get a pointer to `A` instead of the full object. This way, you don't really need the definition of `A` before `B`.

Therefore:

headerfile_1:

```
#include "headerfile_2.h"

struct A{
    B bb;
};
```

headerfile_2:

```
typedef struct A A;

typedef struct b{
    void (*func0)(A *a); /* A * instead of A */
} B;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code as you give it got it wrong at different places. I suppose you wanted `A` to be a `typedef` to `struct a`?

The easiest is to always put the `typedef` as forward declaration in **one** header file

```
typedef struct a A;
typedef struct b B;
```

Then you'd have to have the declarations of the `struct` themselves in the right order (without any other `typedef`). Here your `struct b` only needs a pointer to `A` so this is fine with only the `typedef` above. But `struct a` needs the whole `B` and not only a pointer so your declaration of `struct a` must *see* the whole declaration of `struct b`.