# error C2016 (C requires that a struct or union has at least one member) and structs typedefs

Tags: c, struct, include, project-structure

In my C-project there are some entities. For every entity there are header file and a source file. In the header file I define couple of structs.

For example, let's say our entity is `Baz`. Then we have `baz.h` and `baz.c`. Inside `baz.h` there will be something like:

```
typedef struct baz_t {
    int i; 
    char c;
} Baz;

typedef struct bazbaz_t {
    Baz *b;
} BazBaz;
```

In the same way, I may define an entity `Foo` which it's struct contain a pointer to another struct. Something like:

```
typedef struct foo_t {
    Baz *b; 
} Foo;
```

So in conclusion, every entity can have several structs and a struct can have a pointer to another struct in the same entity or a pointer to a struct from another entity.

Finally, those structs (obviously) should be used by other files in the project.

I've created a `main.h\ main.c` which `#include`s all the entities and each entity have an include to `main.h`. I've also added include-guards in order to avoid circular dependency.

**Problem is:**
I get all those C2016 errors; I've tried to move the `typedef`s to `main.h` but problem haven't been solved.

How do I solve this problem? I am more then certain there's a right paradigm to handle this kind of situation, but I'm relatively new with C.

Comment: Having two instances of `typedef struct baz_t` is going to give you trouble. Call one of them `baz_baz_t` instead? Then consider not having `_t` as a type: that's reserved by some platforms.

Comment: It was a typo (fixed). I'd be glad if you could refer to the actual problem..

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10032068/1866196

Comment: It smells like circular dependencies. Is some .h files included into other .h files? In this case are you sure about dependencies of structs?

Comment: *"...also added include-guards"* more popularly called Header Guards.

Comment: I don't see anything wong with your example. Please give us an example that generates the error. I don't think you should include `main.h` in your entity's `.h` files. It should be a purely hierarchical include structure. P.s.: my VC2008 doesn't have a C2016

Comment: please post a short example the demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a your newly created typename `Baz` as a name here:

```
 Baz *Baz;
```

it is sort of the same as doing:

```
int int;
```

which is also illegal, because ìnt` is a typename.
If you change it to:

```
Baz *baz;
```

it should work.

Comment: That was a typo too. Thank you for noticing, yet that's not the problem I'm facing with.

Comment: then it might be because of your include guards. You can consider using a forward declaration: `typedef struct someType;`.  This creates an *incomplete type*, but pointers to incomplete types are ok.